# Differential equation slope field and cauchy solution

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

Given the differential equation

```
$2y'=\frac{yx}{x^2+4}+\frac{x}{y}$
```

- I have to draw the slope field in a rectangle called `$P$`,
  containing the point`(2,1)`.
- Then in appropriate interval I have to find the solution of the
  Cauchy problem for the given differential equation with initial
  equation `$y(x_{0})=y_{0}$ where $(x_{0},y_{0})$` is inputed by
  clicking in the rectangle `$P$`
- and in the same rectangle `$P$` the graph of the found approximation
  of the Cauchy problem with given initial equation given above .

Here is my solution:

```matlab
function Plotslope
x=-5:0.6:5;
y=-6:0.6:6;
delta=0.2; 
hold on
axis([-5,5,-6,6])
daspect([1,1,1])

for k=1:length(x)
        for m=1:length(y)
          eps=delta/(sqrt(1+ff(x(k),y(m))^2));
          plot([x(k)-eps, x(k)+eps],...
         [y(m)-eps*ff(x(k),y(m)),...
           y(m)+eps*ff(x(k),y(m))],'k');
        plot(x(k),y(m),'k.','LineWidth',0.2) 
        end
end

[x0,y0]=ginput(1);
plot(x0,y0,'bo')
[T,Y]=ode45(@ff,[x0,5],y0);
[T1,Y1]=ode45(@ff,[x0,-6],y0);
plot(T,Y,'r',T1,Y1,'r')

function z=ff(x,y) 
    z=(y*x)/(2*(x^2+4))+x/2;
end
end
```

My question is how can I write the solution to the 3rd bullet : "and in the same rectangle $P$ the graph of the found approximation of the Cauchy problem with given initial equation given above ." or I have already solved it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  We're not really a code review site but we do answer specific questions. What are you having trouble with?  See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: You might find our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) helpful.

Comment: Okay ,thank you I will post it there,but if someone can answer here it will be nice too

Comment: @SecretAgentMan I have changed the post to be a question!